# Store item from array of objects in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "created": "2022-04-07T18:40:11Z",
        "updated": "2022-04-07T18:40:19Z",
        "deleted": null,
        "accounts": [
            "89084",
            "34342"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "created": "2022-01-07T18:40:11Z",
        "updated": "2022-01-07T18:40:19Z",
        "deleted": null,
        "accounts": [
            "99084",
            "38342"
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I store all `accounts` fields into a single array. Notice `accounts` is an array inside an object inside an array of objects.

Comment: you are probably looking for flatMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#flatMap`. To remove duplicates, if any, you can use `new Set()`.

```
const output = input.flatMap(({accounts}) => accounts);
```

```js
const input = [{"id": 1,"name": "Name 1","created": "2022-04-07T18:40:11Z","updated": "2022-04-07T18:40:19Z","deleted": null,"accounts": ["89084","34342"]},{"id": 2,"name": "Name 2","created": "2022-01-07T18:40:11Z","updated": "2022-01-07T18:40:19Z","deleted": null,"accounts": ["99084", "38342"]}];

const output = [...new Set(input.flatMap(({accounts}) => accounts))];

console.log( output );
```

Comment: I like this approach. I was going to go with map and flat, but this is a touch nicer with the removal of duplicates!

Comment: you dropped this } :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to use a map function to extract the data into a new array ( by default the map function creates a new array ). So if you had to do that onto your array it'd be something like this:

```
const newArray =yourArray.map(item => item.accounts)
```

In case you want all your items into one single array and then you'd actually have no nested arrays you'd use this

```
const newArray =yourArray.flatMap(item => item.accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let new_array = [];
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name 1",
    created: "2022-04-07T18:40:11Z",
    updated: "2022-04-07T18:40:19Z",
    deleted: null,
    accounts: ["89084", "34342"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Name 2",
    created: "2022-01-07T18:40:11Z",
    updated: "2022-01-07T18:40:19Z",
    deleted: null,
    accounts: ["99084", "38342"],
  },
];

for (i in data) {
  for (j in data[i].accounts) {
    new_array.push(data[i].accounts[j]);
  }
}

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this the following way:

```
let consolidated = []
for(entry in data) {
    consolidated = [...consolidated, ...json[entry].accounts]
}
```

Simple and only uses a single loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: I defer to the superior one-liner of Ghost's answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
res=[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "created": "2022-04-07T18:40:11Z",
        "updated": "2022-04-07T18:40:19Z",
        "deleted": null,
        "accounts": [
            "89084",
            "34342"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "created": "2022-01-07T18:40:11Z",
        "updated": "2022-01-07T18:40:19Z",
        "deleted": null,
        "accounts": [
            "99084",
            "38342"
        ]
    }
];

var accounts=[];
res.forEach(function(el) { 
    accounts=accounts.concat(el.accounts);
})

console.log(accounts);
```